# redirect nginx ingress controller requests to external domain

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i have an nginx ingress controller and i would like to redirect whatever requests coming in to an external domain, i.e, i dont have a service hosted for it in my cluster. Is it possible to do it?  I tried below with an non existent service, but it did not work

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: external-redirect
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^/$ https://www.external-website.com permanent;
spec:
  rules:
    - host: your.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: non-existent-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know if the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: **Note**: If no host is specified, the rule applies to all inbound HTTP traffic through the IP address specified as described in the [Ingress rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-rules).

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? Did it help you solve problems?  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using rewrite we have an annotation **`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect:`** . Which will permanently redirect (Return Code 301) instead of sending data to the upstream. For example **`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect:`** `https://www.example.com` will redirect everything to an [example.com](http://example.com) .

Similarly `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/temporal-redirect:` annotation also redirects temporarily, which allows you to return a temporal redirect (Return Code 302) instead of sending data to the upstream.

Use below example permanent `annotations` :

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:`  `/`

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect:`

Refer to Github [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#permanent-redirect) for more information.

Comment: should i have that non existent service entry in the ingress?

Comment: Yes, you can have that non-existent service entry in ingress. Refer to similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993607/passing-parameters-down-to-permanent-redirect-in-ingress-nginx) & [Ingress rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-rules) for more information.